# "Reply T to unsubscribe" in SMS spam messages, ignore or reply "T"?

Tags: spam, sms

I'm in China and I occasionally get spam SMS messages. Most of them ends in a sentence that says this or something else alike.

> Reply T to unsubscribe.

(T is the leading letter in Chinese word "unsubscribe")

According to other answers and questions about spam **emails** on this site, it's better to ignore them (and optionally reply T to those identified, trusted message sources like my ISP).

Is it really safer to ignore and mark as spam/junk, or reply something hoping I'll get unsubscribed from 'em?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152854/are-there-any-security-risks-in-replying-to-an-sms-message

Comment: Short answer : don't.  Long answer : check above comments links.

Comment: "Safer" to ignore? Yes. "More convenient if I get unsubscribed?" That's not about safety anymore.